# DataGridView second row with different format

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, formatting

As you can see in the image, the second row has a different format.
Even if I try to sort the data changing the content of the second row, it still happening.
How mayI solve this problem and set the same format for every single row?

I already verified my codebehind and there is nothing that could be causing this.

[image]

Comment: what happen to row no 4 ?

Comment: _I already verified my codebehind and there is nothing that could be causing this_ Well something **is** causing this. We can't tell you what it is if you won't show it to us. (BTW, this could occur from _many_ different places)

Comment: @TzahMama I already commented my whole codebehind and nothing changed... Want me to update my question with the codebehind ?

Comment: @dotnetstep there is no row 4, not yet...

Comment: It is __always__ in the code.  Unless something is broken. How do the data get into the DGV? Bound?

Comment: @TaW With a *DataTable + BindingSource*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` property of your `datagridview`. 
 If you set there some other Style values.
This property used if you want that odd rows of your `datagridview` have other style then `DefaultCellStyle`

If you want same style for all rows, then use `RowsDefaultCellStyle`, and reset `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` or set same values as in `RowsDefaultCellStyle`